# Finding ways to reduce duplication

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to understand the concept of simplifying design. Below is a code with two classes with the same functionality.

```
interface Factorial {
   long factorial(long n); 
}

class FactorialA implements Factorial {
   long factorial(long n) {
     // imperative implementation goes here
   }
}
class FactorialB implements Factorial {
   long factorial(long n) {
     // recursive implementation goes here
   }
}
class FactorialB implements Factorial {
   long factorial(long n) {
     // functional implementation goes here
   }
}

...
class FactorialTest {
   @Test
   public void testFactorialA() {
      testFactorial(new FactorialA());
   }
...
   private void testFactorial(Factorial f) {
     assertThat(...)
   }
}
```

How would I reduce duplication in this case?
I have tried putting them in one class and making the methods static, but I am stuck on how would I call that. I have also attempted an interface as per above, but in that case, the unit testing would be plagued with duplicate tests. Any helpful tips would be appreciated, as this will help me reduce redundancy in my code. How can I condense the code above into one class, with reduced redundancy in testing?

Comment: Your classes are so similar you could just have one class and specify the message to print on a per-instance basis.

Comment: So im trying to apply this concept with something I am working on. 
Basically I have a program about factorials that does it 3 different ways. Recursive, imperative, and functional. When I make tests, I end up making duplicate test for each of the methods. I want to reduce that and have one whole test that encompass it all.

Comment: If that's the question you want answering, you should probably post that instead of the one you posted.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want your one class to look like, can you edit your question to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification in your comment I would do this:

```
interface Factorial {
   long factorial(long n); 
}

class FactorialA implements Factorial {
   long factorial(long n) {
     // imperative implementation goes here
   }
}
class FactorialB implements Factorial {
   long factorial(long n) {
     // recursive implementation goes here
   }
}
class FactorialB implements Factorial {
   long factorial(long n) {
     // functional implementation goes here
   }
}

...
class FactorialTest {
   @Test
   public void testFactorialA() {
      testFactorial(new FactorialA());
   }
...
   private void testFactorial(Factorial f) {
     assertThat(...)
   }
}
```

So the test code is not repeated, but you still have a passing/failing unit test for each implementation.

If you prefer to have each implementation as static methods then you could do:

```
class Factorial {
  static long imperative(long n) { ... }
  static long recursive(long n) { ... }
  static long functional(long n) { ... }
}

class FactorialTest {
   @Test
   public void testFactorials() {
      testFactorial(n -> Factorial.imperative(n));
      testFactorial(n -> Factorial.recursive(n));
      testFactorial(n -> Factorial.functional(n));
   }
...
   private void testFactorial(Function<Long,Long> f) {
     assertThat(...)
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it with the interface and also did the multi test. But the thing is, they are all functions of factorial - one is doing it imperatively, recursively and functionally. How would I invoke that?

Comment: I have clarified above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your primary problem is how to avoid replicating tests for each of your implementations of the interface.

Assuming you are using JUnit then I would recommend using parameterized tests with a method source. This allows you to have a single method that generates an instance of each implementation.

The solution would look something like:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("factorialProvider")
void testConstants(Factorial impl) {
    assertEquals(1, impl.factorial(1));
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("factorialProvider")
void testInduction(Factorial impl) {
    for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
        assertEquals(impl.factorial(i) * (i + 1), impl.factorial(i + 1));
}

static Stream<String> factorialProvider() {
    return Stream.of(new FactorialA(), new FactorialB(), new FactorialC());
}
```

You can have as many tests as you want using the same provider.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and as it seems to be ideal for my problem.